# IntelliJ android SQLite not updating

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ 14 Ultimate (preview version) with PhoneGap to develop Android application. I have configured DB data source to show SQLite DB from Android but IntelliJ is not retrieving latest DB changes all the time.

I run my app that insert something in SQLite on Android device (real device, not emulator), close app, refresh DB source in IntelliJ and its not showing the latest changes. I do that several times and at some point it gets updated, but i can't figure out why it doesn't work all the time.

Comment: Yep i have the exact same problem, and we are not alone, but there isn't any fix that i know of. I saw it mentioned in IntelliJ bug tracker..

I noticed that you need to close open table tab and stop db then refresh, to make it work. It took me a while to figure it out :)

You may find DB browser for SQLite useful, but you will probably need to have root access to device to withdraw DB via ADB pull.